# How to add delay on mouse-out

Tags: jquery, animation

I have tried to implement other solutions but have had no luck... hoping someone can help solve my hover delay problem... I just need to add a short delay on mouse-out.

Thanks in advance!

```
            $('.forward').css({opacity:0, right:0});
            $('.hover-area').hover(function() {
                $(this).find('.forward').stop()
                    .animate({right:20}, {queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutCubic'})
                    .animate({opacity:'0.95'}, {queue:false, duration:400, easing:'easeOutCubic'});
            },function() {
                $(this).find('.forward').stop()
                    .animate({right:0}, {queue:false, duration:550, easing:'easeOutSine'})
                    .animate({opacity:'0'}, {queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutSine'});
            });
```

Comment: have you looked at hoverintent?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I did have a look... it would work as well, but I was hoping to do it without an additional plugin. I'm sure I'll migrate to it eventually... seams like a lot of developers are using it

Comment: Still no solution... looks like I'll be using hoverintent sooner than I thaught

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout()` for make delay on `mouseout`.

```
$('.forward').css({opacity:0, right:0});

    function toogler(element, showHide) {
        if (showHide == 'show') {
            $(element).find('.forward').stop().animate({
                right: 20
            }, {
                queue: false,
                duration: 300,
                easing: 'easeOutCubic'
            }).animate({
                opacity: '0.95'
            }, {
                queue: false,
                duration: 400,
                easing: 'easeOutCubic'
            });
        } else {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(element).find('.forward').stop().animate({
                    right: 0
                }, {
                    queue: false,
                    duration: 550,
                    easing: 'easeOutSine'
                }).animate({
                    opacity: 0
                }, {
                    queue: false,
                    duration: 300,
                    easing: 'easeOutSine'
                });
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

    $('.hover-area').hover(function() {
        toogler(this, 'show');
    }, function() {
        toogler(this, 'hide');
    });​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p4enD/10/)**

Comment: This is more elegant if you only have to call the animation code for one single object, from one place, since it is inline and closure is preserved.

However, you should break the animation code out into its separate function if you need to call it from more than one place

Comment: Would you mind providing an example for breaking the animation into separate functions... I'll be using this for both left and right, e.g. forward backward. Thanks again!!

Comment: Have a look at the other answer(s), which address this. :)

Comment: just noticed that if you hover for a long period of time that it fades out... it should not fade out on mouse-over.

Comment: Add a global varialbe: var mouseInTime = {}. Each time you hover over an object, do mouseInTime[this] = new Date().getTime(); In the mouse-out function, get the time difference by var delta = new Date().getTime() - mouseInTime[this]; and act accordingly

Comment: @Taylor Do you check my last update demo? It seems working just fine

Comment: You might want to define the animation properties somewhere else rather than in the middle of an IF statement, to increase maintainability :)

Comment: Your last update appears to work well... I will give that a go... Thanks!

Comment: Is there is clean way to reuse your code for say both a .forward and .backward... maybe store left and right values in data- or variables?? thanks again for all the help!

Comment: The demo seems to get a little confused when you mouse over and out a few times!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) function, which will call a function after a given period of time. It is also advisable to keep track of where a call to the animation code exists chronologically, so that you don't run into animation artifacts.

```
var MOUSEOUT_ANIM_THRESHOLD = 5000;
var mouseInTime = {};

function onMouseOut( object, serial ) {
   if( serial < onMouseOut.serial ) {
       return;
   }

   $(object).find('.forward').stop()
       .animate({right:0}, {queue:false, duration:550, easing:'easeOutSine'})
       .animate({opacity:'0'}, {queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutSine'});
}

onMouseOut.serial = 0;

$('.forward').css({opacity:0, right:0});
$('.hover-area').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.forward').stop()
        .animate({right:20}, {queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutCubic'})
        .animate({opacity:'0.95'}, {queue:false, duration:400, easing:'easeOutCubic'});

    mouseInTime[this] = new Date().getTime();
},function() {
    var deltaTime = new Date().getTime() - mouseInTime[this];

    if( deltaTime < MOUSEOUT_ANIM_THRESHOLD ) {
         setTimeout(onMouseOut, 250, this, onMouseOut.serial++); //250ms delay
    } else {
          $(object).find('.forward').stop()
              .animate({right:0}, {queue:false, duration:0})
              .animate({opacity:'0'}, {queue:false, duration:0});
    }
});
```

Comment: This did not work... .forward remains active even after mouse-out